# With python how can I have the start of my weeks start on Wednesday instead of Sunday or Monday?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `gmtime, strftime and datetime.`

To give context I am setting up an on call schedule, and to allow people to easily switch people's on call schedules I wrote a script to change the xml file to accomplish that. To make it a bit easier on everyone on call I set the script up so that you can ask what the week number of a specific date is. Most of the built in functionality uses Sunday or Monday as the starting date, and that is not what I need.

The Function in question:

I know `%U` starts on Sunday, I just need a work around so that it will calculate for it to start on wednesday.

```
`#option 2
def getWeek():
    print("\n\n")
    date = input("Enter the date you want the week number of (MM DD YYYY): ")
    if(len(date) != 10):
        print("You typed it in wrong. Try it again.")
        getWeek()
    else:
        d = time.strptime(date, "%m %d %Y")
        print(strftime("%U" + 2, d))`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just manually calculate week # yourself.
Basic algorithm:

- Get current day of year
- Shift back to the nearest Wednesday (or whatever day you want)
- Divide by 7 + 1 = Week # (assuming the first partial week is 0)

In code:

```
>>> wednesday = 3    # sunday = 0, monday = 1, etc.
>>> week_no = lambda d: (d.tm_yday - (d.tm_wday-wednesday)%7) // 7 + 1
>>> week_no(time.strptime("10 06 2016", "%m %d %Y")) # Thursday
41
>>> week_no(time.strptime("10 04 2016", "%m %d %Y")) # Tuesday
40
```

Sanity Check:

```
>>> time.strftime("%U", time.strptime("10 06 2016", "%m %d %Y"))
'40'
>>> time.strftime("%U", time.strptime("10 04 2016", "%m %d %Y"))
'40'
```

Comment: Thank you AChampion, I appreciate the help. I didn't know you could do the labda d: thing with wednesday. That's really cool!